# Monitor bandwidth used per site

Tags: windows-7, web-browser, monitoring, bandwidth

I'm looking for a program or extension that is able to monitor how much bandwidth is used per site browsed. If I visited the same site multiple times in a day, I'd like the total bandwidth used for that site to be displayed (for that day).

The browser I am targeting is Chrome, so I guess the answer will be some sort of Chrome extension, but I am happy to accept an answer that works regardless of browser type. 
The computer system is Windows 7.

Why do I want to do this?
I have a lousy data plan and find that sometimes Chrome uses an excessive amount of data. I share the computer, so it is difficult for me to identify who or what is causing the excessive use. I've optimized Chrome so it shouldn't be doing any unnecessary downloads etc., and have come to the conclusion that it is most likely due to a specific site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GlassWire's Firewall Software](https://www.glasswire.com/download/).

[image: screenshot]

It shows the bandwidth per server and per app.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could try 10-Strike Bandwidth Monitor with the sniffing packet agent for gathering network addresses the host is exchanging with.